# $\left(V_{\pi(\alpha)} \right)^M = \pi \left( V_\alpha \right) $, where $\pi: V \rightarrow M$ is an elementary embedding

Tags: set-theory, proof-verification

Let $\pi: (V;\epsilon) \rightarrow (M;\epsilon \restriction M)$ be an elementary embedding from $V$ into a transitive class $M$. Furthermore, let

- $V_0 = \emptyset$.
- $V_{\alpha+1} = \mathcal P(V_\alpha)$
- $V_{\lambda} = \bigcup_{\alpha < \lambda} V_\alpha$

denote the cumulative hierarchy and for each $\alpha$, let $\left( V_\alpha \right)^M$ denote $M$'s version of $V_\alpha$. I now want to argue that
\begin{eqnarray*} \left(V_{\pi(\alpha)} \right)^M = \pi \left( V_\alpha \right) \end{eqnarray*}
for every $\alpha \in On$.

I am done, if I can say that
\begin{eqnarray*} V \models x \in V_\alpha \Leftrightarrow M \models x \in V_{\pi(\alpha)} \end{eqnarray*}
So, let me see. By elementarity, we get that
(*)\begin{eqnarray*} V \models x \in V_\alpha \Leftrightarrow M \models x \in \pi(V_\alpha) \end{eqnarray*}
The latter holds iff $x$ actually is an element of $\pi(V_\alpha)\cap M = \pi(V_\alpha)$. As far as I'm concerend, I now only have to check $\pi(V_\alpha) = V_{\pi(\alpha)}$ from $V$'s perspective.
For $\alpha = \emptyset$, we have that $V_\emptyset = \emptyset$ and $M \models \forall x (x \not \in \pi(V_\emptyset))$, i.e. 
\begin{eqnarray*}\pi(V_\emptyset) \cap M = \pi(V_\emptyset) = \emptyset = V_{\pi(\emptyset)} = V_{\emptyset}\end{eqnarray*}
As $\pi(\beta+1) = \pi(\beta)+1$, we get the case that $\alpha = \beta +1$ for free.

Finally, let $\alpha$ be a limit ordinal and assume the claim below $\alpha$. Then

\begin{eqnarray*}V \models x \in V_\alpha \Leftrightarrow V \models \exists \beta < \alpha (x \in V_\beta) \Leftrightarrow M \models \exists \beta < \pi(\alpha) (x \in V_{\pi(\beta)})\end{eqnarray*}
As $\pi(\beta) \ge \beta$ and each $V_\pi(\beta)$ is transitive by elementarity, we get that
\begin{eqnarray*}M \models \exists \beta < \pi(\alpha) (x \in V_{\pi(\beta)}) \Leftrightarrow M \models \exists \beta < \pi(\alpha) (x \in V_{\beta}) \Leftrightarrow M \models x \in V_{\pi(\alpha)}\end{eqnarray*}
and thus the claim.

Please let me know if there is any (even slight) mistake in the given argument, because I want to make sure to get the basics right before dealing with the more delicate arguments to come... Thanks in advance!

Comment: I haven't checked your proof, but the following would do. $V\vDash V_\alpha = V_\alpha$. Thus, by elementarity, $M\vDash V_{\pi(\alpha)} = \pi(V_\alpha)$.

Comment: @GME I am not sure how to put this in a formula to get your result. It seems to me as if you considered $(V_\alpha)_{\alpha < \kappa}$ for a large enough $\kappa$ and then looked at "$V_\alpha$ is the $\alpha$-th element in the above sequence". Am I right?

Comment: The formula we apply elementarity to is "$V_\alpha = x$" which has parameters "$\alpha$" and "$x$". The value of $x$ in this case happens to be $V_\alpha$ itself.

Comment: @GME Yeah, that's basically what I thought you did. Thank you very much :-)

Comment: @Rene Forgive my ignorance, but where would you think the argument uses $V_\alpha \in M$?

Comment: Sorry I was to hasty.

Comment: @Rene No worries. I am glad about every comment that helps me to make sure that I didn't mess up :)